# FSx windows file system cleanup of directory by AWS lambda monthly basis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-fsx

I'm creating a lambda and trying to delete a specific directory/subdirectory of FSx but i didn't found any api for this scenario on this [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/fsx.html) API's are only for FSx storage-volume-level not for files and subdirectory level which is not helpful. Please suggest if anybody achieved this in their projects.

Thanks!